# Display time with different timezone giving wrong value using moment

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to display time with 3 different time zone.

**eg. Considering "America/Mexico_City" as standard. 

1. "America/New_York" is 1 hr ahead of Mexico_City

2. "America/Los_Angeles" is 2 hrs behind of Mexico_City**

But I am getting exactly opposite o/p -> New York showing 1 hr behind && Los Angeles is 2 hrs ahead.
o/p -> 
**Mexico_City-> normal ->Jun 11, 2018 19:12 PM

       New_York-> 1 hr ->Jun 11, 2018 18:12 PM

       Los_Angeles-> 2hr ->Jun 11, 2018 21:12 PM**

```
var date = "2018-06-11T14:12:43";
var LastModifiedDate = {
        date: date,
        tzId: "America/Mexico_City",
        tzCode: "PDT" 
}
       console.log("Mexico_City-> normal ->" + utils.formatDate(utils.convertPlatformDateToMillis(LastModifiedDate)));

        LastModifiedDate = {
             date: date,
             tzId: "America/New_York",
             tzCode: "PDT"
         }
        console.log("New_York-> 1 hr ->" + utils.formatDate(utils.convertPlatformDateToMillis(LastModifiedDate)));
        LastModifiedDate = {
            date: date,
            tzId: "America/Los_Angeles",
            tzCode: "PDT"
        }
        console.log("Los_Angeles-> 2hr ->" + utils.formatDate(utils.convertPlatformDateToMillis(LastModifiedDate)));


class Utils {

        convertPlatformDateToMillis(pltDateObject) {
           return momentTimeZone.tz(pltDateObject.date, pltDateObject.tzId);
        }

        formatDate(dateInMillis) {
           return moment(new Date(dateInMillis)).format('MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm A');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newYork = momentTimeZone.tz(moment(), "America/New_York");// Jun 12, 2018 10:00 AM
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles"); //Jun 12, 2018 07:00 AM
var mexico = newYork.clone().tz("America/Mexico_City"); // Jun 12, 2018 09:00 AM
```